# What algorithm/approach is best for a multiclass classifier where there are a significant amount of misclassifications in the source data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, boosting

I am using document embeddings (100 dimensions) to train a classifier on text data, however, I am getting poor results which I am attributing to the fact that there are a large proportion of misclassifications in the source data used to train the model (~10%)

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how best to deal with this issue and the best algorithm to use?

Comment: The term of art you're looking for is "label noise." Here's a survey article to help get you started Frénay, Benoît, and Michel Verleysen. "Classification in the presence of label noise: a survey." IEEE transactions on neural networks and learning systems 25.5 (2013): 845-869.